# mysql performance website tables

Tags: database-design, mysqli, mysql, sql-scripts

*Hello everyone,*

I am designing a website and want to build a database which deals with comments, searches, holding all information, users,  and holds all information. I want to know if there is more than one way to create efficient tables and speed up performance by either turning it into several tables or is there another way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of way to design a database. You can ask a hundred people about some database design, I'm pretty sure you'll end up with more than fifty different answers.

Some people only work is to do database design, nothing else, it can be a full time job.

Your question is way too vague to give you precise advise. Maybe with more informations, someone can give you some pointers to specific tutorials or give you some hints on how to do things.

Sadly, I don't know any good website about this matter, but I can recommend you a book : ["Beginning Database Design: From Novice to Professional"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597699) by Clare Churcher. I don't know if it's the best book about this subject, but I find it pretty easy to understand.